# Cannot get include path working

Tags: php, include

I am trying to include a php directory that is currently in a subdirectory by either editing the php.ini configuration file or with the following method:

```
string set_include_path ( string $new_include_path )
```

I am currently trying to use the above method and have placed it in a **login.php** *(same subdirectory as the php directory that is to be included)* file so I can set the path. Here is what I have:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/dt2/php');
```

The current path is echoed out with `echo get_include_path();` and the following is printed to the page:

```
.:/usr/local/lib/php-5.3.13/lib/php:/dt2/php
```

I understand that the different paths are separated by colons.

In the directory **dt2/php** there is a **library.php** file that contains the following function:

```
function testFunction() {

    echo "hello";

}
```

The function is then called in **login.php**.

However, I get the following error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function testFunction() in /hermes/bosnaweb06a/b2320/(domain name here)/dt2/login.php on line 25

I would appreciate any help and thank you for your time in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is in your dt2 where your homepage is (probably), you need to include full path to dt2: /hermes/bosnaweb06a/b2320/(domain name here)/dt2/php

At the moment it is looking path from your server root: /dt2/php/

Comment: I realized the **(domain name here)** is actually the username to access the web host control panel. However, it shouldn't make a difference. 

Here is the new method: `set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR. '/hermes/bosnaweb06a/b2320/ipg.usernamehere/dt2/php');`
However, I still get an error: 

Fatal error: Call to undefined function testFunction() in /hermes/bosnaweb06a/b2320/ipg.usernamehere/dt2/login.php on line 25.

Comment: what does echo give you now?

also, you still have to use include("your-function-file.php") after you have set include paths.

Comment: It works now with the include("library.php"). I wasn't aware that the separate include(); was required. Thank you so much!